# GitHub Pages not reflecting my actual HTML

Tags: github-pages

I've a GitHub Pages repository with only one branch, `master`. Normally it doesn't freeze after changes. For example, normally it takes around 2 minutes to refresh a HTML that was updated through a pull request.

However, recently I updated my HTML and the change wasn't reflected so far, after at least 16 hours. I've tried to clear the browser cache.

This is the GitHub Pages repository's HTML that I've updated whose changes haven't been reflected:

- https://github.com/hydroper/hydroper.github.io/blob/master/cv.html

Here's it rendered:

- https://hydroper.github.io/cv.html

To make it clear, I've added a card at the bottom of the page with a label "Tic Tac Toe". It renders as expected locally. On GitHub Pages it doesn't render as expected.

Comment: https://github.com/hydroper/hydroper.github.io/actions/runs/4939369180 says that it's queued. All earlier ones have run: https://github.com/hydroper/hydroper.github.io/actions. GitHub may be running slowly?

Comment: @TRiG Oh, that's strange. It never used to stay like this. It has been more than 20 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can diagnose problems like this by clicking on "github-pages" in the right hand navigation of [your repository](https://github.com/hydroper/hydroper.github.io).

[image]

That takes me to a list of deployments.  The latest was on May 9th, which I believe should be for the tic-tac-toe addition to your site.

[image]

If you click on the "deployed" link there you can see a log of the job that ran to copy your files to your site.

[image]

It reports the status as "success."  However if I click into that artifact exchange URLs, I see errors:

> `{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The user 'System:PublicAccess;aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa' is not authorized to access this resource.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.UnauthorizedRequestException, Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server","typeKey":"UnauthorizedRequestException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}`

It looks like these errors prevented the deployment from working.  The deployment pipeline manager doesn't recognize that there are problems and thinks the site was deployed fine.

This is Github's problem.  There are two things you can do:

1. Contact Github and ask for support.
2. Make another change to your repository to trigger another deployment.  This time you know how to dig into it and make sure it succeeds.